# Method overriding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, overriding, virtual

This is a rather simple question, I have a base class which implements common GUI elements, and a series of child classes which I want to override a given method, so they can implement their own behavior on a common control (namely, Prev and Next buttons).

So I have this

```
public class MetalGUI : BaseGUI {
    new protected void OnGUI()
    {
        base.OnGUI();
        if(GUI.Button(prevRect, "BACK", "ButtonLeft"))
            OnPrev();

        if(GUI.Button(nextRect, "NEXT", "ButtonRight"))
            OnNext();

    }

    virtual protected void OnPrev(){}
    virtual protected void OnNext(){}
}
```

and this is one of the child classes

```
public class MissionSelectGUI : MetalGUI {
    new void OnGUI()
    {
        base.OnGUI();
    }

    new protected void OnPrev()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("mainMenu");
    }
    new protected void OnNext()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("selectPlayer");
    }
}
```

(both classes have been stripped off the stuff non-essential for this case)

The thing is that when I have a member of `MissionSelectGUI` instantiated, the `OnPrev` and `OnNext` on `MetalGUI` is getting called instead of the overriden methods. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `new` shadows (or hides) the method (it creates a *new* method with the same name). To *override* it (thus adding an entry in the class' vtable), use `override`. For instance:

```
override protected void OnPrev()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("mainMenu");
}
```

Comment: @Lacrymology Well, sure, it's a bit more verbose, but it gives you more control over your code's behavior.

Comment: To add a bit onto what Etienne said: a "new" method will only be called if you're referencing the object as the derived class. If you're referencing the derived class as the base class, it will call the base method. This could be incredibly useful in some theoretical case I have never run into.

Comment: @Mannimarco I mostly use `new` to silence the compiler when it whines about me declaring a method with the same signature as a method in the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using the overrides keyword not the new one. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier.

Answer (score 2):

Your using the new keyword in your derived class on your OnPrev/OnNext methods - what you want to do is "override" the base class methods eg use the override keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have not overridden the methods, just hidden them using `new`.

This is how you would override them (and allow further classes to override this implementation):

```
override protected void OnPrev()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("mainMenu");
}
```